# Image on screen?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I am making a program in python that will determine if a image is present on the screen and if it is say so. currently I can't get it working and am unsure what is wrong

```
import time
import os
from PIL import ImageGrab
import base64

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('screenshot.png')

time.sleep(1)

with open("screenshot.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print str
img1 = str

with open("test.PNG", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print str
img2 = str  

clear()

if img1 in img2:
    print("images are the same")
else:
    print("images are not the same")

print("This line will be printed.")
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal ? Always add full error message (Traceback) in question (as string, not screenshot)

Comment: maybe you should use PyAutoGUI. It has [Locate Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions)

Comment: there are no error messages. It isn't working in the sense that it can not detect the sample image within the screen shot. Also the screenshot code is the only one that I found that runs with no errors.

Comment: you should put this information in question. Did you use the same image for test ? Two images can be compressed in different way. You should have to uncompress before you compare - use `from PIL import Image` and `Image.open()`

Comment: Using Image.open() Doesn't give me a string that can be compared to a sample it gives "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=1366x768 at 0x2C0A698>" and "
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1366x768 at 0x2C0A620>" while my current method gives me a string. I have also tryed BMP file format which also didn't work.

Comment: using `PIL` and `Image.open()` you get uncompressed image and you don't need string because it can compare images using `==`. BTW: normal `open()` gives you compressed data and the same image in two files may use little different compression so strings will be different but uncomressed image will be the same.

Comment: BTW: `Image` had method `tostring()` but now you have use [tobytes()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=tobytes()#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) to get raw data - `img1.tobytes() == img2.tobytes()` (or shorter `img1 == img2`)